# Peterson's solution with single variable

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, critical-section

```
do {
    turn = j;   // = (1-i)
    while(turn==j);
    //critical section 
    turn = j; //exit section. 
} while(true);
```

Can peterson's algorithm work with just the turn variable. Why is the flag variable required?

Comment: I have a *very* hard time deciphering your pseudo code. that inner while loop - is that supposed to have NO body at all?

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, it's supposed to lock the thread until the condition is false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this simplification of Peterson's Algorithm not provide process synchronization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385998/why-does-this-simplification-of-petersons-algorithm-not-provide-process-synchro)

Answer (score 0):

Yes obviously. Using this approach, the Progress condition is not satisfied.
Clearly, here s process `j` will move forward (i.e. get out of busy wait at `while();`) if and only if someone else changes the `turn` variable to its own id (say `i`).

Thus clearly, the progress of process `j` is in hands of process 'i'.

For eg. Suppose the other process got busy in a non critical section area above the critical section. Or maybe the other process is killed/ deadlocked etc. Then this poor process `j` keeps waiting forever.

Comment: isn't this a problem with the proper implementation as well? Process j is depend on process i for 'progress' (by making it's flag false) 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm)

Comment: No no, Not at all, its not happening in the solution at WIkipedia.
Look bro, the best and easiest explanation possible is mentioned in the Book:- Modern OS by Tanenbaum - 3rd edition, Pg 123, Peterson Soution.