# Why does a simplification of Peterson's Algorithm using a single 'turn' variable not provide process synchronization?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, locking, mutex

I'm reading "[Operating System Concepts](http://iips.icci.edu.iq/images/exam/Abraham-Silberschatz-Operating-System-Concepts---9th2012.12.pdf)" and trying to make sense of Peterson's Solution (on page 208), an algorithm for ensuring two processes sharing memory do not access the shared resource at the same time (potentially creating a race condition).

In Peterson's Solution, there are two shared variables that help with synchronization: "boolean flag[2]" and "int turn". "flag[i]" indicates whether a particular process is trying to enter its "critical section," the section where it accesses shared data. "turn" contains one of the two processes' indexes (0 or 1) and indicates which process' turn it is to access the shared data.

Peterson's algorithm (for process i, where the other process is denoted by j) is below:

```
do {
    #set flag to say I'm trying to run
    flag[i] = true
    #let the other process have a turn
    turn = j
    while(flag[j] == true && turn == j);

    #enter critical section

    flag[i] = false

    #do non-critial remaining stuff

} while (true);
```

Why does the following simplification of Peterson's algorithm not also provide process synchronization? If I understand why not, I believe it will help me understand Peterson's algorithm.

```
#initialize turn to i or j
do {
    while(turn == j);

    #enter critical section

    turn = j;

    #do non-critial remaining stuff

} while (true);
```

In this simplified algorithm, it seems to me that a given process i will continue while looping until the other process j finishes its critical section, at which point j will set "turn = i", allowing i to begin. Why does this algorithm not achieve process synchronization?

Comment: Feel Free for any queries.

Comment: It works by randomly assigning a winner, your replacement requires the processes to strictly take turns.  Not the same thing.  Don't assume that this algorithm actually works, it is far too simplistic for modern multi-processor machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because **there is a chance of starvation in  the simplified version.**

As you mentioned:

> j finishes its critical section, at which point j will set "turn = i",
>   allowing i to begin.

Ok, now say `Process i` finishes and will set `turn = j` . Now if `Process i`, **again** wants to enter critical section, it cannot enter as `turn = j`. The only way for `Process i` to be able to enter Critical Section is `Process j` again enters Critical Section and sets `turn = i`.

So, as you see the simplified version requires that **the processes must enter critical section in strict alternation, otherwise it will lead to starvation.**